# Can I create a custom role in Sql Server Reporting Services (SSRS) (2019)?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2019

I would like to create a custom role to mimic 'Browser', but not give the user access to subscribe to reports.  I noticed that there is a 'Roles' table in the ReportServer database that lists out the current roles, along with a TaskMask and RoleFlags column.  I do not want to attempt to tweak any of these columns b/c I don't know how they work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create roles via SSMS. Connect to the reportserver instance rather than the usual database engine.

[image]

Just right-click 'Roles' and add a new role. As you can see I added a "folder browser only" role previously.

When you create you new role you can exclude the highlighted option.

[image]

Comment: What do I do if SSRS is installed on the same instance as the database engine?

Comment: Nevermind.  I figured it out.  I never connected to anything other than a database engine before so connecting to Reporting Services was new to me.  I will try out your suggestion.  Thanks!

Comment: I tested out the custom permission and it works perfectly!  Thank you!